Have I converted this DB table to the correct number of dimension tables for a star schema correctly?
I'm trying to replace a pretty complicated query for a dashboard. We currently use this system where we track practices, phone numbers and start/end dates partially in an excel spreadsheet and also in a database. Whenever we want to update any of the info, like which practice uses which number during which time period, it is a very involved process that includes checking numbers and practices in excel to make sure that nothing is duplicated, etc. If we want to change something so that practices share a line we have to go into the db and combine the names, etc. I think the entire process could be simplified if we used a star schema instead of the system that we currently have.
We currently have a database table with the following schema
| Group Practice | Practice | TransferType | DialedNumber | DigitsDialed | StartDate | EndDate|
I think the table should be broken out into the following dimensions:

Practice

| PK | Group Practice | Practice |

Phone Number

| PK | DialedNumber | DigitsDialed |

TransferType

| PK| TransferType |

Calendar Table

There would be a fact table at the center that would track "Transfer Volume by Practice".
A phone number can have one or more transfer types for one or more practices simultaneously.
For example, (123)456-7890 could be transfertype1 for practice A from Jan 1, 2024 - Feb 1, 2024. It could then be used as transfertype2 for practice B from Feb 2, 2024 - Mar 1, 2024.
Or Number (234)567-8901 could be transfertype 2 for practice C from Jan 1, 2024 - Feb 1, 2024 and it could simultaneously be transfertype 3 for practice D from Jan 1, 2024 - Mar 1, 2024.
I've read textbook definitions of how to set up a star schema but I want to make sure that I'm doing this correctly. Do my dimensions make sense? Would this capture the "slowly changing dimensions" in the data?
